# prove that the greatest number of regions that $n \geq 1$ circles can divide the plane is $n^2-n+2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

This is an induction problem, but I have no idea how to do something like this. Any hints?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Assume that you already have $k$ circles, and draw one more.

1. At how many points will that new circle intersect the earlier ones - at maximum?
2. How many arcs is that new circle split into (by those points of intersection)?
3. How many pre-existing regions are split in two (at maximum)?

Comment: I wonder if a little projective geometry could make this easier. Been a lot time since I've studied inversion with respect to a circle, however.

Comment: Is it clear that you can always draw the circle in a way that it intersects the earlier ones at the maximum number of points?

Comment: A good question, Eckhard. I would do the following, proving that the $n$ circles have a common interior point. Assume that we have drawn $k$ circles in the prescribed way. Pick a point from their common interior. Draw a line through that point. It will intersect all the circles twice. Then you can either bend that line to form a huge circle (most of it outside all the circles) so that it still intersects all the circles twice, there will be an $\epsilon>0$ of room to play, or do a suitable Möbius transform for same effect.

Comment: ... and, of course, you have take a modicum of care to make sure that the points of intersection are all distinct. That only rules out a finite number of choices for the direction of that line, so is of no concern.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Suppose that the result holds for $n$ and consider an arrangement with $n + 1$ circles.  Pick a circle $C$.  In at most how many points in total can $C$ meet the other $n$ circles?